# W8 jQuery events not working

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8

I have a strange problem with my PhoneGap W8 app. I have following code, which works in Firefox, Chrome, IE10 browsers and Android,iOS devices:

```
$('#mainPage').bind("pageshow", function(data){
    alert("main pageshow");
});
```

When I start to debug my app with W8 emulator, events like the one above don't work. I know that jQuery does not officialy support W8, but PhoneGap usues IE10 browser which is actually supported by jQuery Mobile.

Do you know any solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait, jQuery Mobile [doesn't support Windows 8](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) yet.

Did you try change the `bind` event to `live` or `on`?? That might help. Something as below

```
$('#mainPage').on("pageshow", function(data){
    alert("main pageshow");
});
```

Comment: I know there is no support. But there may be the way to get around of it. Phonegap supports IE10, which is the engine used to build W8 apps. That gives some possibilities.

Comment: @Borewitsch did you try as I said in the answer?

Comment: I tried it earlier. Btw live is not supported as of jQuery 1.9.

Comment: yep, I know `live` is depreciated as of 1.9 (y)